# Compare Objects with DateTime properties in PHPUnit

Tags: php, datetime, phpunit

Suppose I have two objects with the following structure:

```
class Item {
     public $id;
     public $date;
}
```

In a unit test, I'd like to test the equality of two items. E.g.:

```
class MyTests extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testDummy() {
        $item1 = new Item();
        $item1->id = 1000;
        $item1->date = new DateTimeImmutable('now');

        $item2 = new Item();
        $item2->id = 1000;
        $item2->date = $item1->date->modify('+1 second');

        // For my use case, I'd consider these two items equal.
        $this::assertEquals($item1, $item2); // FAILURE :(
}
```

Is there a clean/simple way compare these objects and use a delta in case PHPUnit encounters a `DateTime` object?

I know I can use `$this::assertEquals($item1->date, $item2->date, '', 10)` but given my object I'd rather not write assertions for each property.

Thanks!

Comment: How are the two instances equal? The `date` property is one second apart. What constitutes "equal" for your use case?

Comment: Why do you add one second and even think it is equal? There are milliseconds in DateTime.

Comment: The case you use as an example does not even make sense, of course the contents of two objects are equal if you set them equally. If you want more comfort tho, I'd have a look into `Reflection`.

Comment: It seems you need to write [custom assertions](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.custom-assertions).

Comment: @ishegg For my use case I settle for a date that's close enough to my expected object. Adding a single second is just an example. This might also be 1 microsecond.

Comment: See an answer on ClockMocking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47024013

Comment: I can see what he's asking.  He wants to test that some function results in a DateTime() object with "now" as the time, but just comparing the result to a DateTime created as a baseline will fail because of differences in microseconds between creation. I have a very similar issue.

Comment: So... "These two DateTime objects are equal, give or take one second"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to implement an `equals` method in your `Item` class and just test for its return value in your test like this:

```php
class MyTests extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testDummy() {
        $item1 = new Item();
        $item1->id = 1000;
        $item1->date = new DateTimeImmutable('now');

        $item2 = new Item();
        $item2->id = 1000;
        $item2->date = $item1->date->modify('+1 second');

        $this->asserTrue($item1->equals($item2));
        $this->asserTrue($item2->equals($item1));
    }
}
```

for an `Item` similar to this one:

```php
class Item
{
    const OFFSET_TOLERANCE = 1;

    public $id;
    public $date;

    public function equals(self $item): bool
    {
        // in case the id is relevant as well
        if ($this->id !== $item->id) {
            return false;
        }

        // not sure how you prefer to handle the following 2 cases
        if (null === $item->date && null === $this->date) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!($this->date instanceof DateTimeInterface) ||
            !($item->date instanceof DateTimeInterface))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $interval = $this->date->diff($item->date);

        // note that you can also use $interval->f
        // to compare microseconds since PHP 7.1
        return $interval->s > self::OFFSET_TOLERANCE;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there is no `__equals` method like in Java.

The only alternative solution I can think of is to implement a `__toString` method that returns a somehow representative value of your `Item` object, containing i.e. the timestamp without the last digit.

But in terms of readability and reliability and to ensure you are explicit about your implementation, I recommend to go for a solution similar to the example above.

Answer (score 0):

$item1= date('D, d M Y');

$item2 = date('D, d M Y', strtotime("+1 day"));

try this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what will be the basis on the type of [test result] you need to for this given test case. But if you want to test if both objects are equal:

- Compare the two objects based on its [instance]
- If there's a case that one property uses the [DateTime] object

Then I would propose the ff. assertions:

```
class MyTests extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testDummy() {
        $item1 = new Item();
        $item1->id = 1000;
        $item1->date = new DateTimeImmutable('now');

        $item2 = new Item();
        $item2->id = 1000;
        $item2->date = $item1->date->modify('+1 second');

        // Option 1: Check if given object is an instance of [Item] class
        $this::assertEquals($item1 instanceof Item, $item2 instanceof Item);

        // Option 2: Check if given property for each assigned variables is an instance of [DateTimeImmutable] class
        $this::assertEquals($item1->date instanceof DateTimeImmutable, $item2->date instanceof DateTimeImmutable);
    }
}
```

Hope this will guide you well.