# Compare object with datetime properties without microseconds

Tags: php, unit-testing, datetime, phpunit

As of new phpunit versions \DateTime objects are compared with microseconds precision. It's not always a good idea, because if I have an object like this:

```
class QueueItem
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')));
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')));
    }
}
```

I'll never be able to use `assertEquals` for the whole object in my tests, because datetime properties will always be different due to microseconds.

It's not a big deal when just comparing objects (I can compare each field separately). But here comes the problem:

```
$expectedQueue = [
    new QueueItem(),
    new QueueItem()
];

$this->repositoryWrite
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('save')
    ->with(...$expectedQueue);
```

`with` compares the whole array of the arguments including datetime properties, which I can not predict.

The only solution I've got is using `willReturnCallback` and comparing each argument separately:

```
    $this->repositoryWrite
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('save')
        ->willReturnCallback(function(...$queue) use ($expectedQueue) {
            /** @var QueueItem[] $queue */
            foreach ($queue as $k => $queueItem) {
                $this->assertEquals($expectedQueue->getSomeProp(), $queueItem[0]->getSomeProp());
            }
        });
```

It looks... well, strange. Are there other solution for this one? Can I change comparator's precision for \DateTime objects?

Comment: Have you tried the `DateTime::format()` method? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: `assertEquals()` has an optional `$delta` parameter for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann Yes, but there's no such parameters in MockObject's `with`. This is what I'm talking about.

Comment: But `with()` uses constraint objects. Just use it with `equalTo()`.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann, it would be a quite complex constraint. It seems like Hast is trying to test multiple things all together. If I get it, `QueueItem`s are used in the class under test, and assertion in the mock is intended to confirm the objects were constructed properly somewhere in the class. Apparently the  `equalTo`  should be applied to all properties of `QueueItem` instances to use correct $delta for `DateTime` ones.

Comment: @Hast, try to use **same** instances of `QueueItem`s  created in the class under test to assert parameters the mock.

Comment: @AlexBlex actually, Sebastian's approach may work here. I'm gonna try it and I will write a comment here once it's done.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann Well, Alex was right: If I'm comparing objects, delta will affect all its properties, not only the ones with date. Which compromises testing results.

Comment: @Hast, try to test 1 thing at a time: one test to write the queue, another one to create `QueueItem`s. I could give a full answer if there was a code snippet of what you are testing.

Comment: @AlexBlex i will update my question soon providing the example

Answer (score 3):

Testing times can be quite difficult - and with the move to a default high-resolution in PHP7, it did get more 'interesting'. In your first example. it might not be so hard - set a `$now = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));` and set the fields, but that gets a lot harder inside a class that you are testing that you may not have such easy control over.

However, with a little PHP Namespace hacking, you can override (on a limited basis), some of the base language functions, like `time()`, and `sleep()`.  The Symfony component, '[phpunit-bridge](https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge)', provides a ClockMock class that can override `time()` to control the clock - and turn `sleep(10)` into a `time()+10` call - turning a real-time pause in a test into an almost zero-time event, and making comparisons exact.

It can only do so much, and can't override a `DateTime()` constructor, but it's easy enough to replace that with something that will use `time()` to set it -- `$now = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U', (string) time());` and so be controlled with the ClockMocking.

You can just install the [PHPUnit Bridge](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html), and then just use the ClockMock class in your tests (with that little extra use of time() to create new DateTime's).

I'm using the PHPUnit-bridge in my tests, and to enable the Clock Mocking I can just annotate the test class with '@group time-sensitive' (if it's following the usual style of naming the class it is testing with a `Test\` prefix and `...Test` classname suffix), and the bridge will recognise that, and automatically enable mocking on the class - or I can start it up manually in the test code for other classes.